# Styles for overflow-y: scroll; not shown on mobile/tablet

Tags: css, mobile, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I have a browser-based mobile application and I want to highlight a vertical scroll that is in a certain section. The default vertical scroll styles for mobile/tablet are very subtle and many users overlook scrolling down in this section.

I show below my code and it works great in Google's mobile devices development tools but when I test it on a real mobile, none of my styles are shown, only the default mobile/tablet vertical scroll styles.

What can I do to make my code work for mobile devices?

Thanks!!!

```
<style>
    .introText{ 
      width:400px;
      height:200px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    
        scrollbar-face-color: #367CD2;
        scrollbar-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
        scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FFFFFF;
        scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFFFF;
        scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    /* scroll started */
    .introText::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 12px;
    }
     
    /* Track */
    .introText::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
     
    /* Handle */
    .introText::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    }
</style>


    <div class="introText">
        <p>
            "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
        </p>
        <p>
            <h5>Another</h5>
    
    "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
        </p>
    <div>
```

https://codepen.io/lleoun/pen/abEyZwG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The webkit properties you are trying to use might not be supported on all browsers. You can check the compatibility [here](https://caniuse.com/)